# Spring 3 : Binding same controller method to multiple form action

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-3

I have a controller method with RequestMapping.PUT and having a URI

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/add/email", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String addNewAccountEmail(@Valid @ModelAttribute EmailClass emailObject, BindingResult bindingResult, Model model) {
    return displayForm(model);
}
```

I have a form like :

```
<form:form id="add-user-email" action="/add/email" name="manageUserAddEmail" method="post" modelAttribute="accountEmail">
```

I want to have more **form** pointing to same **action** , but need to do different operations inside **addNewAccountEmail** method. So how can I achieve this in Spring ? Basically any parameter which can make me differentiate functionalities or somehow I can have multiple methods having same RequestMapping URL and Method ?

I can only use RequestMethod.POST as I have similar requirements for other methods as well.

Basically I do not want the URL to change in Browser when invoking actions, that is why I want all form actions to point to same action URL.

Comment: It's completely unclear what you're asking. What is Add Account Email, Add Parent Email? What is `com.abcd.AllURLS.user_email`?

Comment: Edited question. Let me know if you have any doubts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could point all of your forms at the same controller method and then differentiate the form-specific functionality within that method by looking for form-specific request parameters.

Each form would need to add its own request parameter to identify it - such as:

```
<input type="hidden" name="form1_param" value="1"/>
```

And then you can vary the behaviour inside the method by inspecting the `HttpServletRequest`:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/add/email", method = RequestMethod.POST, )
public String addNewAccountEmail(@Valid @ModelAttribute EmailClass emailObject, BindingResult bindingResult, Model model, HttpServletRequest request) {

    if (request.getParameter("form1_param") != null) { // identifies 1st form
        // Do something
    } else if (request.getParameter("form2_param") != null) { // indentifies 2nd form
        // Do something else
    }

    ...
}
```

It would be cleaner however to have multiple controller methods mapped to the same path, but specify different params in the `RequestMapping` - to differentiate the different forms.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/add/email", params="form1_param", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String addNewAccountEmail1(@Valid @ModelAttribute EmailClass emailObject, BindingResult bindingResult, Model model) {

    // Do something specific for form1
    return displayForm(model);
}
```

And also:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/add/email", params="form2_param", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String addNewAccountEmail2(@Valid @ModelAttribute EmailClass emailObject, BindingResult bindingResult, Model model) {

    // Do something specific for form2
    return displayForm(model);
}
```

Etc.

Answer (score 1):

[`@RequestMapping`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestMapping.html) accepts arrays as parameters (with an *or* semantic).

```
@RequestMapping(
    value = "/add/email",
    method = { RequestMethod.POST, RequestMethod.PUT } )
```

Comment: Using multiple methods is not option for me. I need to use same method and value but somehow needs to support multiple functionlities. Either using multiple methods or make the same method differentiate functionalities ?

Comment: Why do you think I suggest to use two methods? Read again carefully the answer. It's exactly what you want.